# Binding a FlipView with GridView

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, flipview

I have a GridView binding with a data source  which works perfectly.

```
public void LoadXmlData(string dateOfRunAsString)
{
    IEnumerable<RetrieveFromXml> processList = from process in xmlDocument.Descendants("Process") 
                                               where process.Parent.Parent.Attribute("Date").Value == dateOfRun 
                                               select new RetrieveFromXml(process.Attribute("Name").Value, Convert.ToDouble(process.Elements("ActiveTime").Sum(sec => (int)sec)));
    NameGrid.ItemTemplateSelector = myTemplateSelector;
    NameGrid.ItemsSource = processesList;
}
```

Now the Problem is I need to Combine the Gridview to a flipView.

Like the FlipView will display a gridview for each day.

Something Like

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
    flipview.list.add(processfromxml(date+i));
    //Consider processfromxml() is returning a Ienumerable List
}
```

So that the FlipView will display the GridView for first day and on clicking next it displays the GridView for Next day.

Please help how to Achieve this in XAML ,C# in windows 8

This is my Underlying Class to fetch data.

```
public class RetrieveProcessFromXml
{
    private string name;
    private double activeTime;

    public RetrieveFromXml(string nameFromXml,double activeTimeFromxml)
    {
        name = nameFromXml;
        activeTime = activeTimeFromxml;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public double ActiveTime
    {
        get { return activeTime; }
        set { activeTime = value; }
    }
enter code here

} //End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You have loop like this

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
    flipview.list.add(processfromxml(date+i));
    //Consider processfromxml() is returning a Ienumerable List
}
```

So if you want to add item in `FlipView`then you have to add `GridView` not `IEnumerable` list. You have to assign `ItemsSource` to particular `GridView`and then add that `GridView`to `FlipView`.

Here I am giving you simple example

XAML

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="MyTemplate">
        <Border Background="DarkGray" Width="100" Height="100">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
                       Foreground="White" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="30"/>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <FlipView x:Name="flipview" Height="500" Width="500"/>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
List<SolidColorBrush> colors;
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    colors = new List<SolidColorBrush> 
    {
        new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red),
        new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Gainsboro),
        new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.BlanchedAlmond),
        new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Turquoise),
        new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Azure),
        new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Teal),
        new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Tan),
        new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.PowderBlue),
        new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.WhiteSmoke),
        new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.SeaGreen)
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        flipview.Items.Add(AddNewGridview(i));
    }
}

int i = 1, j = 0;
GridView AddNewGridview(int k)
{
    var gv = new GridView();
    gv.Background = colors[k];
    gv.ItemTemplate = this.Resources["MyTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
    List<int> IDs = new List<int>();
    while(i < 17 + j)
    {
        IDs.Add(i);
        i++;
    }
    j = i - 1;
    gv.ItemsSource = IDs;
    return gv;
}
```